# How do I explicitly dismiss a toast notification without having to wait for it to disappear on its own?

Tags: system-tray, notifications

On Windows Phone when events of interest happen on the phone such as finding a nearby Wi-Fi network when your disconnected, a new text message arrives or an app wants to let you know something happened when you are not in the app a toast notification is displayed in the system tray area in the user's accent color with a message.

How do I dismiss the toast notification without having to tap it and hit back or waiting for it to disappear on it's own?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply swipe the toast notification to the right and it will leave your screen. If you have multiple pending toast notifications (for instance, if you receive multiple texts concurrently), you will have to swipe each of them in turn. However, this will dismiss them. You don't even have to unlock the phone.