# How can volume dialog be dismissed?

Tags: buttons, volume

When I am playing games in landscape mode I often press the volume button accidentally. That pops up the volume dialog which is very annoying when I am in the middle of some game action.

What is the fastest and easiest way to dismiss this dialog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know of one way I can dismiss this dialog. AFAIK it behaves the same way as the keyboard - so you can dismiss it simply by tapping the **BACK** button.

However, I don't know if this is the fastest and easiest way to do it...

Comment: Since WP7 is very limited in functionality, I think there is no another way.

Comment: +1 The back button is the quickest way. It will immediately hide the overlay.

Comment: Do you want something faster and easier than click an always available button? To me this is the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, that may seem silly, but I have something like [this](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/312/how-do-i-explicitly-dismiss-a-toast-notification-without-having-to-wait-for-it-t) on my mind - flicking or tapping somewhere on the screen. When you are in game, you are not using the back button, so finding it (which side of the phone) and reaching it can take one or two secs. Flicking or tapping could be little faster... But it doesn't work for me, so I wanted to know if anyone found something interesting ;)